# How can I run a jQuery method after posts are loaded in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [Smooth Div Scroll jQuery Plugin](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) to have a moving filmstrip on a website. The images loaded into the film strip are of a custom post type and each have a title and contain a single image. The plugin scrolls horizontally across a long div containing any amount of images. My problem is that I can scroll for a seemingly infinite amount of time even after the images are gone.

**Here's the my breakdown of the problem:**

- I've tried using plain images instead
  of the post loop, and everything
  worked as expected (no infinite
  scrolling).
- I've tried setting scripts between document.ready and window.load, with document.ready they don't load at all.
- I've tried calling a public function "recalculateScrollableArea" so that the area could be calculated after the images are loaded to no avail, then by calling an alert box in jQuery in the script I could see that it was still being called before the images were loaded.

**How it should look usually:**
[image: How it should look usually]
**How it looks when it over-scrolls:**
[image: How it looks when it over-scrolls]

**The Smooth Div Scroll code and the following initializing code are both called at the bottom of the footer:**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
        autoScroll: "onstart" , 
        autoScrollDirection: "backandforth", 
        autoScrollStep: 1, 
        autoScrollInterval: 15, 
        visibleHotSpots: "always"
    });
```

**This is what I did to try and fix the resizing:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("disable");
});
```

I should also mention, the images for the posts are surrounded by "p" tags but I don't see why that would be the issue.

Thanks for reading!

**EDIT:**
Here is some more code, most of it is stock and working when just plain IMGs are place instead of the loop.

**The base CSS and jQuery files are the same as the ones in this simple demo:** http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/basicDemo.htm

**jQuery and jQuery UI Imports (Working)**

```
function jQuery_from_Google() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) { // actually not necessary, because the Hook only get used in the Theme
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // unregistered key jQuery
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.5.2'); // register key jQuery with URL of Google CDN
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); // include jQuery
    }
}
// nur for Themes since WordPress 3.0
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'jQuery_from_Google' ); // Theme active, include function

function jQueryUI_from_Google() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) { // actually not necessary, because the Hook only get used in the Theme
        wp_register_script( 'jqueryui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js'); // register key jQueryUI with URL of Google CDN
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryui' ); // include jQueryUI
    }
}
// nur for Themes since WordPress 3.0
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'jQueryUI_from_Google' ); // Theme active, include function
```

**Imports take place at the bottom of the footer:**

```
<?php // Smooth Div Scroll inport for filmstrip galleries ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/javascript/filmstrip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/SmoothDivScroll-1.1/js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.1-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's a snippet of code for one section which uses a loop for content:**

```
<?php if(is_page('engagements')) { ?>
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <div class="scrollingHotSpotLeft"></div>
    <div class="scrollingHotSpotRight"></div>
    <div class="scrollWrapper">
        <div class="scrollableArea">
            <?php 
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'engagement_photos' );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    the_content();
                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } else if(is_page('weddings')) { ?>
```

**Here's an example of adding an image in WordPress:**
[image]

Comment: All browsers?  Link to your page?

Comment: I'm developing on a localhost server right now so it's still not online. The problem is occurring in all browsers.

Comment: It might help if you posted all relevant code then... not much troubleshooting can be done with what's been posted so far.

Comment: Ok, I added a bunch of information in an edit, if there's anything else that would be needed just let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I tried putting in regular hardcoded imgs which worked fine and then wrapped them in "p" tags which produced the same issue. I guess I was just over-thinking the problem. Sorry. Now to figure out how to get the loop to just produce the imgs.

Comment: fixed that too, it just required a <?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?> at the top of the template. Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the following code in the functions.php file.

```
function init_my_scripts()
{
    if (!is_admin())
    {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_deregister_script('jQuery UI Core');
        wp_register_script( 'jQuery UI Core', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js'); // register key jQueryUI with URL of Google CDN
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery UI Core' ); // include jQueryUI

        wp_register_script('filmstrip', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/javascript/filmstrip.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('filmstrip');

        wp_register_script('smoothDivScroll', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/SmoothDivScroll-1.1/js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.1-min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('smoothDivScroll');

    }
}

add_action('init', 'init_my_scripts');
```

Of course, you can change the jQuery CDN to Google CDN, change 'template_directory' to 'stylesheet_directory', etc.

Comment: I found the answer to my problem, but just for future reference what does this code do exactly? Should I always register jQuery plugins in the functions file?

Comment: It's the best practice. You may want to check the links listed in the Resources part of the wp_enqueue_script function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script